# django-selenium TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: django, selenium

Doing a simple test of a clicking dropdown and seeing if the menu is displayed.

```
    dropdown_user = self.browser.find_element_by_id('dropdown-user')
    dropdown_user.click()
    expanded = dropdown_user.get_attribute("aria-expanded")
    self.assertTrue= (expanded)
    settings = self.browser.find_element_by_id('dropdown-user-settings')
    self.assertTrue(settings.is_displayed())
```

Gives me this error when I run the test. I cant figure why settings is a str.

```
   self.assertTrue(settings.is_displayed())
   TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: it appears that in this specific case, `settings.is_displayed` is a string rather than a method. You can validate that by printing the result of `type(settings.is_displayed)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Printing it actually gives me:
<class 'method'>
?!?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment (not enough rep) or I would - could you post the whole stack trace? The line `self.assertTrue= (expanded)` looks like it could feasibly cause an issue.

Edit: I think you're assigning the value of the variable `expanded` to `self.assertTrue`, then when you try to call `self.assertTrue` you're trying to call a string, rather than a function. Remove the line `self.assertTrue=(expanded)` and replace it with `self.assertEqual(expanded, 'true')`.

Edit 2 to explain in more depth as requested:

The value of `expanded` is a string - probably 'true', if your dropdown is expanded.

Writing `self.assertTrue=(expanded)` is the same (in this case) as writing `self.assertTrue=expanded`. You're assigning the value of the variable `expanded` (which is a string) to the variable `self.assertEqual` - it is no longer a function, it's a string!

```
self.assertTrue(True) # fine
self.assertTrue=('Woops!') # the value of self.assertTrue is now the 
                           # string 'Whoops!'
print(self.assertTrue)
>'Woops!'
self.assertTrue(True) # you're trying to call a string here
> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

In python, there's nothing to stop you from assigning any type to any variable, because it's [dynamically typed](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Why%20is%20Python%20a%20dynamic%20language%20and%20also%20a%20strongly%20typed%20language).

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.
I think that is the whole stack trace.
Not sure if pytest is hiding anything else.
But the whole output is just my code with that error at the bottom

Comment: Try removing the line `self.assertTrue=(expanded)` and re-running - you're assigning the `assertTrue` function the value of expanded with that line, making it a string rather than a function, causing your error.

Comment: Nice find!
Commenting out the `self.assertTrue=(expanded)` works
I am a little confused though.
Is this and issue with using self.assertTrue twice in one test?
Since I want to have both of the test is it impossible?

Comment: Commenting here since I can't comment in response to your conversation with Bryan Oakley - printing the value of `type(settings.is_displayed)` and it being `<class 'method'>` confirms that `settings.is_displayed` is not the issue - thats the type you'd expect it to be!

Comment: I'll edit my answer again to explain more fully what's going on.

Comment: It's definitely possible to test both in the same test - change `self.assertTrue=(expanded)` to something like `self.assertEqual(expanded, 'true')`

Comment: ohhhh I'm an idiot. I just need to remove the = sign   ...
Great explanation. Sorry i dont have enough rep to upvote

Comment: Glad you fixed it!